# How many peers does bitcoind try to connect to?

Tags: bitcoind, peers, peer-discovery

Let's say a new node try to connect to the network.
Since it doesn't have any node in its peers.dat it makes a request to the DNS seeder and receives a list of addresses.

Now, how many of these addresses will it try to connect to?
What about the same when retrieving addresses from peers.dat?
Is it possible to alter this number by using some option?